# VSCode Arduino can't find Arduino CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-cli

I'm using (trying) the VSCode Arduino extension with arduino-cli. When trying to compile a sketch, it throws this error:

```
Cannot find Arduino IDE. Please specify the "arduino.path" in the User Settings. Requires a restart after change.
```

this is the output from `arduino-cli version`:

```
arduino-cli.exe  Version: 0.21.1 Commit: 9fcbb392 Date: 2022-02-24T15:41:45Z
```

and these are all the `arduino.` settings in `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "arduino.useArduinoCli": true,
    "arduino.path": " C:\\Users\\[name]\\scoop\\apps\\arduino-cli\\0.21.1",
    "arduino.defaultBaudRate": 9600,
    "arduino.logLevel": "verbose",
    "arduino.commandPath": "arduino-cli.exe"
}
```

Comment: Odd, I had the same issue (also installed via scoop), but forgot to tick the 'useArduinoCli' option in the extension settings. After that, it worked.
One thing I can think of: did you do `arduino-cli config init` after installing the CLI? Maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @mxt3 I have a config

Comment: Just FYI, I have 
 `"arduino.path": "C:\\Users\\[name]\\scoop\\apps\\arduino-cli\\current","arduino.useArduinoCli": true` 
and no commandPath.  That's all. No idea if that matters.

Comment: @mxt3 I removed `arduino.commadPath`, and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was setting it up today and ran into the same issue. In your case try it with this path:

```
"arduino.path": " C:\\Users\\[name]\\scoop\\apps\\arduino-cli\\0.21.1\\bin",
```

I am on fedora and installed the cli with brew and this path is working for me:

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/arduino-cli/0.26.0/bin
```

and I have the Command Path set to:

```
arduino-cli
```

hope this works!